# Builiding a hash of hashes of arrays with variables in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference

```
my %cellHash
```

has different keys, $`cellDirectory` contains the value of the desired key.

I am trying to assign a hash as value of the current key (`$cellDirectory`).
That hash has only 2 keys, and each of them has a different array as value.

```
%{ $cellHash{$cellDirectory} } = (
'R1Tests'  => \@fastqcResults_R1 ;
'R2Tests'  => \@fastqcResults_R2 ;
);
```

However, when I try to run the script, it returns a syntax error near this part of the code.

I don't know what I am doing wrong... any ideas?

Comment: Might help if you show the syntax error

Comment: Also $cellhash{$celldirectiry} can only hold a scaler so remove the %{ } from around it then replace your curve brackets ( ) with curly brackets { } on the right hand side to allocate a hash ref to the scaller

Comment: Are you sure about this? Npw I'm confused...

Comment: It more just for clarity, Most people would just allocate hashref on the right handside rather then derefrence a hash on the left hand side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The semicolons inside the list are the problem.

```
%{ $cellHash{$cellDirectory} } = (
    R1Tests => \@fastqcResults_R1,
    R2Tests => \@fastqcResults_R2,
);
```

**Update:**

In response to a question in a comment, this is what I would do instead.

The anonymous hash syntax (reference literal) would be my first choice:

```
$cellHash{$cellDirectory} = {
    R1Tests => \@fastqcResults_R1,
    R2Tests => \@fastqcResults_R2,
};
```

This is also valid, though I like it less:

```
my %newHash = (
    R1Tests => \@fastqcResults_R1,
    R2Tests => \@fastqcResults_R2,
);

$cellHash{$cellDirectory} = \%newHash;
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt! Are the curly braces and % around  $cellHash{$cellDirectory} correct syntax? The comment in my post above has me doubting.

Comment: Technically, it's correct, but in practice, you wouldn't see it very often. Rather than dereferencing on the left-hand side, I would probably assign directly to a hash reference on the right-hand side. IMO, it's more direct and more readable that way.

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: Updated answer with a couple examples.

Comment: Thank you for your examples. It does seem now like an unnecessary step what I was doing ;)